# What is the appropriate way to post/submit login information from razor view to controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, passwords, http-post

In my view, I have `@html.passwordfor`, it in contained within a `@html.beginform`. When the user clicks submit and the form is posted back to the controller, the password is available in plain text in the http request body.

What is the correct way to convert that user entered password to a `securestring` type prior to it being sent to the controller `checklogin` action?

I assume it is something to do with the `securestring` type because I am passing the password (and username) to the constructor of `NetworkCredential` which has an overload allowing a `securestring` password rather than a plain text password.

Answer (score 4):

The way html forms are designed; the credentials are sent in the clear between you and the server.  There is no default way of encrypting data that will ensure security.  You can try to use some JavaScript libraries to encrypt the password prior to sending it; but if you are worried about someone intercepting the password; they would be able to intercept your encryption algorithms as well.

The common method of ensuring that the passwords and other sensitive information (Credit cards etc) are secure is to use `SSL`.  This encrypts the entire connection between the client and the server; and it much more secure.

Comment: SSL is all you can count on for the reasons Kami outlines.  Make sure you are using Http POST method, but I suspect if you are using forms that's implicit.